# Spaces between arcs in canvas

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

The goal is to draw a circle having arcs that representing time slices. I have done this:

[image]

The problem is that there is a white space between each arch and I want to remove it. Also, the arcs are not aligned. This is my code:

```
    int x = getWidth()/2;
    int y = getHeight()/2;
    int stroke = 20;
    int radiusExternal = 250;

    final RectF rect2 = new RectF();
    rect2.set(x - radiusExternal, y - radiusExternal, x + radiusExternal, y + radiusExternal);
    for (int i = 0; i < modProgram.getListEvents().size(); i++) {
        ModEvent event = modProgram.getListEvents().get(i);
        Paint paint2 = new Paint();

        paint2.setColor(getColorEvent(event));
        paint2.setStrokeWidth(stroke);
        paint2.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint2.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        paint2.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        int initialAngle = getInitialAngle(modProgram, event.getStartEvent());
        int sweepAngle = getSweepAngle(modProgram, event, initialAngle);
        canvas.drawArc(rect2, initialAngle, sweepAngle, false, paint2);
    }
```

Comment: Look into your initialAngle and SweepAngle functions.  I bet you have an off by 1 error.

Comment: I check this and each angle is the same that the initialAngle of the next arc. It's very strange :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is probably only a partial answer to deal with the gap between the arc-segments**.

Here's a fiddle with javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/oakvLadb/

I've just randomly generated some start- and stop-angles.

The important part lies in the drawing of the arc:

```
ctx.arc(c.width/2,c.height/2,radius,startAngle,stopAngle+anglePadding);
```

The anglePadding is there to make sure that a little extra is drawn. When the next segment starts off being drawn from the previous segment's stopAngle, there will be a slit overlapp, making sure no gap is visible.

**Next for the poor fit of the arc-segments**

When it comes to the fact that it seems like the segments aren't meeting up correctly, the only thing I can think of is that the segments that you're drawing are not those of a perfect circle but an oval, and that's why they're not meeting up correctly. If your `rect2` variable doesn't hold data for a perfect square, your segments won't match.

It looks like you do have a perfect square so they should align. Somewhere, there's a rounding error of some kind...

Comment: Good idea. The extra padding solved my problem as well. Do you happen to know why the gap happens in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing each Arc next to each other, you can draw larger arcs like layer drawing.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can I do that?

Comment: I mean, you can draw new arcs over the last arc drawed. The sweepAngle will be always the same (360) and the initialAngle could be an offset

Comment: He means to try changing the last line to this: `canvas.drawArc(rect2, initialAngle, sweepAngle+5, false, paint2);`, see the +5 on sweepAngle (experiment to see which number works best for you. Try 1-5, that should be enough)? The only problem that arises is the last arc drawn, it should not be drawn with those extra degrees on the sweepAngle

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by setting LayerType to LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE. like below. 
   setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Answer (score 0):

```
export const data = {
  labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Label',
      data: [1298, 1798, 2500, 2200],
      backgroundColor: [
        '#687EEB',
        '#FF4B5F',
        '#AA71F2',
        '#F29741',

      ],
      borderColor: [
        '#687EEB',
        '#FF4B5F',
        '#AA71F2',
        '#F29741',

      ],
      borderRadius: [
        10,
        10,
        10,
        10,

      ],
      spacing: 20, // i think, this is what you need 
      borderWidth: 0,
      cutout: '80%',
      borderAlign: "inner"
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation about your code solution

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33449656)